# AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference app hang on my MX4 device

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I just started to play with AltBeacon library. I downloaded sample app from AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference and added the library reference to [android-beacon-library-2.0.tar.gz](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/download.html) . 
When I ran it on my MX4 device (MeiZu made in China) with Android 4.4, I saw the main activity but it behaved very slow. I clicked start ranging button, the new activity view was not responding as the same; it took many seconds to go back to previous view if I clicked back button. I'm curious about if the library is scanning too much on main thread causing the non-responsiveness, or because it's the device model itself not good fit for the beacon library implementation. Thanks!

ps. I added the iBeacon parser and still didn't see any output in the app, not sure if it's related with the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

While we have not tested the reference code on the MX4, I based on its specs, I don't see any obvious reason it would be a problem.  You can enable debug logging in the library and send a LogCat excerpt from the time the app starts looking for beacons.  If you create a new issue in  GitHub on the open source project and attach the log file, we'll take a look at it.

You can enable debug by adding a line like below to the `onCreate` method of the `BeaconReferenceApplication.java` class:

```
mBeaconManager.setDebug(true);
```

You can create a new GitHub issue on the open source project here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/new

Full disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks and the primary author of the library.

Comment: Thanks, David. I just submitted issue #62 with attached logs: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/62